# How can I switch from clang11 to clang14 on freebsd?

Tags: c++, clang, clang++, freebsd, pkg

hello on my server clang 11.0.1 version is installed but my project is compiled with clang14, when I write the command " pkg install clang14 " I get an error like clang14 not found.

please help me solve this problem, thank you.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6Vq0.png)

I tried to download clang14 from llvm web page but I couldn't install it :(

Comment: You should add the text from your image to the question instead of the image. That looks more like you have an issue with the package manager configuration or your internet configuration. `clang14 not found` appears nowhere in the image.

Comment: "no address record" seems to indicate a DNS issue. Not programming.

Answer (score 0):

clang is part of llvm. There is no package for clang alone. Instead, install llvm14.

But you should first deinstall llvm11 if you no longer need it.

```
pkg delete llvm11
```